# VBA If Else TypeOf vs Select Case TypeName

Tags: vba

I'm writing a function in VBA that has an argument that can be many different types and I want to know what method for checking the type is best and what advantages and disadvantages each method has. I'm considering two methods.

The first method is to use a case select with TypeName.
The second method is to have a large if else statement using TypeOf.

I think method 1 looks cleaner and reads better but could suffer from typos. I think method 2 has compile safety. Is there a method that is generally preferred?

```
'method 1
Select Case TypeName(InputVariable)
    Case "Type1", "Type2", "Type3", "Type4"
        'do something
    Case Else
        'do something else
End Select

'method 2
If TypeOf InputVariable Is Type1 Or_
TypeOf InputVariable Is Type2 Or_
TypeOf InputVariable Is Type3 Or_
TypeOf InputVariable Is Type4 Then
    'do something
Else
    'do something else
End If
```

**Edit:**

Ok I learned something very important that changes everything and I think this will be useful for people to know. Polymorphism and the Implements keyword really effects the situation.

if i have a class foo and a class bar which implements foo then

```
Dim MyFoo As Foo
Dim MyBar As Bar 'Bar implements Foo so its a type of Foo

If TypeName(MyBar) = "Foo" Then
    'this code doesnt run
End If

If TypeOf MyBar Is Foo Then
    'this code does run
End If

If TypeName(MyFoo) = "Bar" Then
    'this code doesnt run
End If

If TypeOf MyFoo Is Bar Then
    'this code doesnt run
End If
```

Comment: @PatrickHonorez no. this is clearly a very specific question involving hypothetical illustrative code, [codereview.se] is for revieweing **all aspects of real, working code**. Illustrative example code like this is explicitly off-topic on CR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best of both? - The type safety of `TypeOf` & the readability/short circuiting advantage of a `Case`:

```
Select Case True
        Case TypeOf InputVariable Is Type1
           ...
        Case TypeOf InputVariable Is Type2
           ...
        Case TypeOf InputVariable Is Type3
           ...
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you. this is a good solution. it even allows me to keep the comma syntax like this:

```VBA
Case TypeOf InputVariable Is Type1, InputVariable Is Type2
```

Comment: @R.Binter note that the instruction separators `:` are redundant/superfluous; `Case` conditions aren't *line labels*.

Comment: see my edit above which I think people will find useful. it really mattered a lot in my case.